# What is the general term for animal "rituals"?

Tags: terminology

I am having a hard time figuring out whether there's a good word for the concept of different animal recurring behavior, such as mating rituals, seasonal migration, nest building, and other "rituals" that animals generally do and redo usually based on what kind of animal they are.

It could be seasonal, such as described above, or even generational, such as when some flying birds always teach their younglings to fly by being coerced out of the nest, and sea turtles hatch on the beach running towards the shoreline. So the repetition is key and is based on a given animal group's biology and social structure.

The best word I've found so far has been "Ritual" based on its usage in mating rituals, but I wanted to know if it is appropriate to use it for general recurring animal behavior given its religious connotations etymologically. I'm also curious about, and I wouldn't mind being enlightened of any possible industry-/faculty-specific terminology that describes and fits what I'm looking for with one caveat; The more well known and simple a word or phrase, the better.

I hope my description of what I am looking for is clear.
Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Isn't that the same with animals as with people? That is, if it's an ordinary, every-day action it's simply a form of behaviour; if it's stylised, it's a ritual? I stand to be corrected and I would list hunting as a behaviour, and mating dances as rituals.

Activities such as nest building have elements of both… the purely practical side of next-building being merely a behaviour and the practically pointless, "flashy" part of nest-building as a ritual. Most birds merely build nests; bower birds make so much of nest-building, it gives their species its name!

Comment: More than instinct?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Yeah, you very well might be right. I think hunting is very much so general that it can be seen as a simple behaviour, so is generally something like eating, breathing, mating, etc. even though they're recurring. What I'm curious about is whether there's a term for the way animals prepare or do some of these things differently from one another, usually species wise. Exactly how we use the word "mating ritual" but just more general hunt tactics, egg-laying, displaying so on and so forth.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yeah, more than instinctually although they're sometimes taught these "rituals" through instincts curiously. Turtles have an egg-laying "ritual" that stems from instincts but results in that yearly "ritual".

Comment: Isn't it 'animal behaviour'?  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003347200916063

Comment: Surely there's a material difference between a *ritual* such as the preening and strutting and chasing pigeons do before mating, and something like a winter migration which is necessary to follow warmth and food. One **is** a ritual [a particular way of doing things which *could* be dispensed with] and the other is actually indispensable. Which behaviour are you asking about?

Comment: Sorry… you lost me completely. How is "the way we use the phrase 'mating ritual' as opposed to" just more general hunt tactics, egg-laying, displaying so on…" not the Answer you're looking for?

Could you look again at your examples? Mating rituals, seasonal migration, nest building, and other things animals do and redo, and the rest, seem very vague, at best.

Can you not find some clear examples?

Comment: @AndrewLeach That's very true, my point was not so much animal migration in general but more the specific way an animal group or species do their migration. Like, some species migrate specifically by following a set path each year, that's in a sense their pilgrimage, their way of doing a general thing such as migration. I am asking about the first behavior specifically, the ritual, so I do guess that is the best answer. My appeal with this question was for whether there was a similar or better word for Ritual in this context that doesn't have the religious connotation.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Maybe Ritual is the answer, I was merely curious if there maybe was possibly a field-specific word or scientific term for animal rituals that doesn't have the religious connotation. At least to a very large degree looking on a macro scale at complex animals, mating is general, hunting is general, consuming and eating is general. However how each species goes about preparing or sets out to do these things can include some kind of "ritualistic" behavior, that can vary from species to species. It's describing that variation difference in one word I'm looking for. Ritual fits best.

Comment: Sorry, Yous0147… when the way any species goes about hunting, consuming or eating is general" doubtless, you will be able to explain that.

Until then you seem to be ignoring your own point, which I thought was that some behaviours are and others are not "ritual." 

Neither in animals nor in humans if mating "general." However hard it might be to analyse the details, nevertheless in both animals and humans, mating is almost exclusively ritual.